# Raid 1 can't install Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, raid, live-cd, compaq

I am trying to install Ubuntu desktop on HP Compaq 8000 from an Ubuntu live CD. I connected two disks in RAID, but in installation type, I can't select nothing.

Comment: When you say you connected the two disks in RAID, do you mean that this is hardware RAID and you configured it before booting, in the RAID controller setup?

Comment: -1, the information Eliah was asking for is very much relevant to answering this question. Instead the question has gone stale.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Alternate Install 32bit](http://mirror01.th.ifl.net/releases/precise/ubuntu-12.04.1-alternate-i386.iso) or [Alternate Install 64bit](http://mirror01.th.ifl.net/releases/precise/ubuntu-12.04.1-alternate-amd64.iso).

For more information on how to install Ubuntu onto a RAID array see the [Installing on external or RAID hard disks section](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation)